# Is there a way to scrape a div id in bs4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

There are multiple div classes that have the same class name but a different id:

`<div class ="starting-lineups__matchup" data-gamepk="******">`

I am able to scrape the data I need within these classes but I keep having to inspect the page to find out the value for data-gamepk. Is there a way to scrape that number?

Here's the site I'm scraping and my code below:

https://www.mlb.com/starting-lineups

```
#main table that contains the data
gamelist = soup.find('div',attrs={'class':'starting-lineups__container-multi'})

user = input()

#game specific data
game = gamelist.find('div',attrs={'data-gamepk':user})

#loop through away team name
for teams in game.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'starting-lineups__team-name--away'}):
    for team_a in teams.find_all("a"):
        print(team_a.text)
```

So all the classes named `'starting-lineups__matchup'` are within the `'starting-lineups__container-multi`' class. All `'starting-lineups__matchup'` classes have a number associated with them. The user manually enters this number to scrape the data within that specific class. Which in the code above would just be the away team name `starting-lineups__team-name--away`.

In order to find the number for each game I have been inspecting the web page. Instead having to visit the website and look through the html myself I want to scrape that number as well as the team names associated with it.

Comment: Would you like to post url? or some code?

Comment: Please add a complete snippet of the HTML code and the data you are trying to extract.

Comment: once you get the element, you can get the attribute. So for example, something like: `soup.find('div',{'class':'starting-lineups__matchup'})['data-gamepk']`

Comment: I just edited the post, hopefully it adds some clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question right: this script will print game number, and home/away team names:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.mlb.com/starting-lineups'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for game in soup.select('[data-gamepk]'):
    print(game['data-gamepk'])
    print(game.select_one('.starting-lineups__team-name--away').get_text(strip=True))
    print(game.select_one('.starting-lineups__team-name--home').get_text(strip=True))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
631112
Cubs
Pirates
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
631432
Rangers
Astros
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
631146
Nationals
Phillies
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
631234
Yankees
Mets
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
631368
Padres
Angels
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
631614
Blue Jays
Red Sox
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
631405
White Sox
Royals
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
631370
D-backs
Dodgers
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
631055
Athletics
Mariners
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup import re

soup= BeautifulSoup(html.text,'lxml') 
results = soup.findAll("div", {"data-gamepk" : re.compile(r".*")})
```

This will list every div with the "data-gamepk" attribute.

PS: using True instead of re.compile(r".*") might also work.